# android 4.0.3 and JavaScript get selection returns empty string

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to get selected text in android 4.0.3 web browser. Here is my code:

```
     $(document).on('selectionchange', function(e) {
           log ('Text is: ' + getSelectedText());
      });
```

And getSelectedText is:

```
function getSelectedText() {
 var text;
   if (typeof window.getSelection !== "undefined") {
     text = window.getSelection().toString();
   } else if (typeof document.selection !== "undefined") {
     text = document.selection.createRange().text;
 }
 return text;
}
```

It works on Android 4.3, but doesn't on 4.0.3. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an investigation on this and found that startOffset and endOffset of selection range are equals.

Moreover they are equal to char index where I started my selection. I mean if I press on the center of the word 'android' `startOffset` and `endOffset` will be 3 and if I will change selection bound startOffset and endOffset will stay the same.

I guess it's a bug, so I had to disable this functionality in my app for this version of android. Sad.